# My redirect rule not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want my web url

http://gpuzzles.com/quiz/small-ridldes/

to redirect to

http://gpuzzles.com/quiz/small-riddles/

but its not working

my .htacess file is inside quiz folder as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /quiz/
Redirect 301 /quiz/small-ridldes/ /quiz/small-riddles/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?url=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

What i want

```
quiz/small-ridldes/ redirects to
quiz/small-riddles/ redirects to  // ----- not working 
index.php         // ----working
```

Comment: In which direction? Are the _incoming_ URIs misspelt as /small-ridldes/ and you want to change them to the correct directory /small-riddles/, or is your directory misspelt and you want to change the incoming URI to the misspelt directory? Also, try omitting the RewriteBase if you're going to give the full path in the Redirect.

Comment: i just want the url to redirect. there is no dir inside quiz folder

Comment: "There is no dir inside quiz folder" means what? "small-riddles" should become "small-riddles.php" or something like that? The first thing I'd try is getting rid of the RewriteBase, so it's not thinking /quiz/quiz/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to mix mod_alias directives (`Redirect`) with mod_rewrite directives (`RewriteRule`). Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /quiz/
RewriteRule ^small-ridldes/$ /quiz/small-riddles/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?url=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: now its not even redirecting to small-riddles
plz check @ http://gpuzzles.com/quiz/small-ridldes/

Comment: @SwatiMajumdar didn't realize the htaccess file is in the `quiz` folder, need to remove the `quiz/` from the pattern.